# Android Application ID for push notifications

Tags: android, parsing, push-notification

i've was reading this Tutorial about push notifications on android
https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

and i came across this line of code

```
Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY");
```

I would like to know where can i find "YOUR_APP_ID" and "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY"

thank you.

Comment: [Sign up for a Parse account to implement this tutorial](https://parse.com/#signup) and to get your ids/keys